# Effective combinations of Shermans out of Blood, Guts, and Glory

Tags: flames-of-war

The new lists for 4th and 7th armored divisions let you mix and match Sherman M4A3s, M4A3 76s, M4A3E8s, and Sherman Jumbos.  The various versions vary greatly in terms of firepower, speed, and points cost, so I'm having trouble coming up with an effective selection.  I would like to have a unit that is as homogeneous as possible, but I'd also like to use some Easy Eights.  Unfortunately, they are limited to only two per platoon.

What are some good combinations of Sherman types for both an Armored Company and as support in an Armored Rifle Company?

Comment: Can I get a reason for the down-vote so I can improve the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Balanced platoon**

In most cases a solid 1-2-2 platoon will do the trick.

- 1 jumbo to act as the shield.
- 2 m4a1 76 mm for fire power.
- 2 vanilla m4a1 or m4a3s, if you think you will benefit from the protected ammo stowage.

This type of platoon will be a great advancing platoon for a reasonable cost.

**Spearhead platoon**

- 2 M4A3 76s or M4A3E8s
- 2 m4a3
- 1 m4a3 105mm

Great platoon to spearhead attacks. All tanks use the *Detroit's Finest* special rule, giving you a slight edge when it comes to flanking and taking objectives.

**Tortoise platoon**

- 1 jumbo to act as the shield.
- 2 m4a3e8; utilize the smooth ride special rule by not moving more than 15cm on any given turn, keeping RoF up while denying penalties.
- Lastly, you can fill it with either m4a1 or m4a3s.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

cant go wrong with   2 m4a3  HQ
                     5 M4a3  platoon  x3 
                     4 M10   TD  platoon
                     3 priest battery  x 2
                     AOP

screw the 76mm sherman  use your brain and detroits finest + smoke wins every games also use patton for REcce deployement  and use youre riest as Assault gun to clear dug in infantry use AOE to counter Ambush ....evrytimes a win  toooooo easy
use this army on a single front of about 2 feet larger outa the whole 6 foot table break trough lines with speed

Comment: This question is about the composition of individual tank platoons, not about the composition of the entire army. Why is your selection better than other options? What does it accomplish that can't be done with something else? And can you clean up your formatting a bit? This answer is hard to read.